# Angular 2 and LeafLet Uncaught ReferenceError: <function> is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet

I have a project in Angular 2 with Leaflet, I would like to call the simple function by clicking the button, but I get

```
ReferenceError: <function> is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

Here is my code. Everything works, but the function not.

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

//layer
  googleStreets = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    maxZoom: 30,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
  });
//!!!The FUNCTION
  test() {
    console.log('test');
  }
constructor () {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.ParseService.getJ().subscribe(data => {
    this.myData = JSON.parse(data);

//set markers and popUps
for(let i = 0; i < this.myData.length; i++) {
  let lat =+((this.myData[i])['lat']);
  let lng =+((this.myData[i])['lng']);
  this.id = (this.myData[i])['code'];

//HERE IS THE PROBLEM. BUTTON APPEARS BUT FUNCTION IS NOT AVAILABLE 
      let popUp = (this.myData[i])['displayName'] +
        '<br/><button onclick="test">Raumplan</button>';

  let markerLocation = L.latLng(lat, lng);
  let marker =  new L.Marker(markerLocation, {icon: customIcon});
  map.addLayer(marker);
  marker.bindPopup(popUp);
}
  });
```

Could you please help me with workaround?

Answer (score 8):

Do not use `onclick` as it's an `HTML` and the function you assign to `onclick` will be searched in global `scope` of `javascript` i-e inside `<script>` tags and this is no more the part of `Angular2`. So what you should try is something like below

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'dynamic-button',
template: '<button type="button" (click)="test()">Raumplan</button>'
})

export class DynamicButton{
public test(): void{
alert("Hi. I am a test call");
  }
}
```

And then

```
let popUp = (this.myData[i])['displayName'] +
'<br/><dynamic-button></dynamic-button>';
```

Answer (score 4):

in angular2 you will bind the event like this:

```
let popUp = (this.myData[i])['displayName'] +
    '<br/><button (click)="test">Raumplan</button>';
```

OR this:

```
let popUp = (this.myData[i])['displayName'] +
    '<br/><button on-click="test">Raumplan</button>';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `(click)="OpenList()"`

```
<button (click)="OpenList()" type="button" class="btn-link btn-anchor">List</button>
```

`Typescript` function

```
OpenList()
 { 
 
 }
```